# Pandas.ExcelWriter not behave the same after pyinstaller to exe file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyinstaller

I am a absolute beginner of python and working on a small program to collect data and write multiple sheets to Excel using pandas, it worked as expected. However after convert to exe file using pyinstaller, it only write first sheet. No matter in onefolder or onefile mode. 
I pasted the minimum code that can recreate the problem.
I know I can just writer.save() once in the end but in real program I writer multiple sheets in for loop and it's a lot more efficient and create much smaller xlsx file than just save once in the end.

PyInstaller: 3.4

Python: 3.7.2

pandas: 0.24.2

Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0

I search the problem everywhere, tried to use hiddenimports to add different modules for pyinstaller, like such:
hiddenimports=['pandas', 'pandas.io.excel', 'numpy', 'pandas.compat', 'xlsxwriter', 'openpyxl'], 
None of them works.

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('xlstest.xlsx')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 2, 3]], columns=("a", "b", "c"))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[5, 6, 7]], columns=("d", "e", "f"))
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet1", index=False)
writer.save()
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet2", index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: are you trying to create multiple excel files, one for each iteration of the loop? Else why would the final file be any smaller than writing the file in each iteration.

Comment: I am trying to create multiple worksheets in one excel file. The finial file size has huge different when I save each sheet from each loop vs save one time outside the loop.

Comment: You shouldn't use `writer.save()` between calls. That isn't supported by XlsxWriter and isn't required anyway, as far as I can see from your example. If Pandas is using xlsxwriter (it can choose since you haven't specified it explicitly, `pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')`), then you will only get one worksheet. If Pandas picks up openpyxl then the double save() may work. That probably explains the differences between the two environments.

Comment: @jmcnamara interesting

Comment: you are right, I should specify the engine='openpyxl', that should avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. I was using Pycharm for the project. It appears that pycharm using a virtual environment while pyinstaller using the local system environment. So I tried to compare the installed packages in both environment and find out what could be the reason. I have same version of pandas and openpyxl installed in both environment, which puzzled me for a while. Tried a lot of things and eventually find out it was XlsxWriter package caused the problem. I have XlsxWriter 1.1.5 installed in local environment but not in pycharm venv. As soon as I pip uninstalled it from local env. My compiled exe file works correctly.

I am still looking into how to correctly using pyinstaller in pycharm venv. Any comment on that is welcomed.